# ASP.NET MVC Emails try catch exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtp

So I'm trying to set up an email flow in my app. 
My problem is the email is not sending.

I've tried debugging using break points and it seems that in the try catch block it's catching an exception.
    `_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766`

Null Exception was caught
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've also noticed my password got caught as null.
Controller:

```
   public JsonResult SendMailToManager()
    {
        bool result = false;

        result = SendEmail("intelht@lotusworks.com","Test","This is a test email");

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }

    public bool SendEmail(string toEmail,string subject,string emailBody) {

        try{
            string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
            string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail,senderPassword);

            MailMessage mailMesage= new MailMessage(senderEmail,toEmail,subject,emailBody);
            mailMesage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMesage.BodyEncoding=UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Send(mailMesage);

            return true;
        }

        catch(Exception ex){
            return false;

        }

    }
```

View:

```
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="SendEmail()"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
</body>


var SendEmail = function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/HolidayRequestForms/SendMailToManager",
        success: function (data) {

            alert("Success");


        }


    })

}
```

I want it so when an employee clicks to submit a holiday request, an email gets sent to managers to start the email flow for the app

Comment: Do you have an smtp server running at smtp-mail.outlook.com:587?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it with sql server database mail and it send fine.

Comment: So it turns out I have a typo setting in setting up my password.

Answer (score 0):

this error usally occurs when sql connection timeout or if the sql server is down.

For more information, you can refer to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/a9371fa1-5a96-44b6-b223-a992d6577ec8

Hope it helps!